# How is the score on top (the ones beside the timer) computed in DoTA 2?

Tags: dota-2

I just started playing DoTA 2 and I'm wondering how the score at the top is calculated. I initially thought it was the total kills of the the team but it doesn't add up to that value. So, how's it computed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of your score as the count of the times an enemy hero has died and vice versa (the opponent team's score is the number of times you and your teammates have died).

Team score counts ALL DEATHS including suicides, denies, even if heroes are killed by creeps/tower (like Bariş mentioned, Non-Playable character kills are considered too).

Killscore, on the other hand, would be the sum of all the kills by each player on one respective team. Come to think of it...Team score is more like a deathcount!

Answer (score 2):

It's indeed total kills of the team, but what you don't consider is the NPC kills. When a non-hero entity kills an enemy hero, kill count of heroes doesn't increase but total kill count does, that's why id doesn't add up.